# Assigning class name to static property of a class

Tags: python, django

folks! How can I assign a class (in the example bellow, 'A') to a static property of another class explicitly? The interpreter is not recognizing 'A'. See code sample bellow:

```
class A:
    """
    Generic class -- nothing special about this particular one
    """
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class B:
    """
    Option 1, not allowed. Interpreter does not recognize 'A'. Why? Is 
    there a way to circumvent this?
    """
    var = A
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class C:
    """
    Option 2, allowed; however, terrible for readability.
    """
    var = None
    def __init__(self):
        C.var = A
```

My idea was for the class to look nice and simple just like when declaring a Django model, where you simply specify the schema as static properties. In this case, though, the property is a class.

Thank you!

Comment: The only way that would not allow the first option is if `A` didn't exist when it happened.

Comment: I kind of remember reading that it needs to use meta-class in python.

Comment: Option 1 has no issues: http://ideone.com/gRrCBQ

Comment: you are right, Ignacio. Actually, the problem occurs when class A is in a separate file, and I import it as 
from separate_file import *

Then 'A' is not recognized when var is declared as in class B.

Any ideas?